# Why would you want multiple render targets?

Tags: rendering, directx11

In d3d11, you can bind multiple render targets [ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476464%28VS.85%29.aspx).  But why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When multiple render targets are bound, they can each be written to individually by the pixel shader -- it isn't (necessarily) the case that all render targets will get the same image. You could write only the red component into one output, only the blue into another, et cetera.

This is used when implementing [deferred rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_shading) for example: position, normal, color, et cetera information are each written to their own render target.

Comment: The new use for 3D TVs is to give multiple local players their own full screen view by filtering only a certain set of the frames to each player. This would be another use for multiple targets.

Comment: +1 for deferred rendering, thats what I've seen it used most for. MRT is also available in DX9 and 10 btw so it's not a new feature.

Comment: @James about time something useful came from that tech hype. :)

Comment: Back in the day it was also used for cube/environment mapping/reflections - there are better ways now though.

Comment: @Daniel http://singularityhub.com/2010/07/26/sony-patents-turn-3d-tv-into-2-shows-at-once-maybe-you-just-want-video-goggles/

Comment: @James, maybe it also has to do with the PS3's ability to render two HD images at once? I recall back that when hyping up the launch, prototype PS3s had 2 HDMI ports to simultaneously display two pictures. Most people thought "really, who has two HDTVs in one room?" Now it's back, in 3D form!

Answer (score 2):

The added benefit to using multiple render targets, as in deferred rendering like Josh mentioned, is that you send the scene's geometry to the vertex shader only once and apply it to different pixel shader outputs, instead of re-sending the geometry for every output you need. This saves a lot of computation time for the GPU. The trade-off for faster GPU performance is higher consumption of frame buffer memory.